# typearea warning in connection with algorithm2e package

Tags: warnings, algorithm2e, typearea

I'm trying to remove some warnings from my thesis but there is one I cannot understand at all. It's some strange interaction between the typearea package and the algorithm2e package. Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\KOMAoptions{
  paper=a4,
  pagesize=auto,
  fontsize=11pt,
  twoside=true,
  BCOR=20mm,
  DIV=13,
  open=right, % new chapter always on right page
  cleardoublepage=current, 
  headsepline=true,
  titlepage=true,
  parskip=false,
  chapterprefix=true,
  captions=tableheading
}
\recalctypearea
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
  \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Package typearea Warning: \typearea used at group level 2.
(typearea)                Using \typearea inside any group, e.g.
(typearea)                environments, math mode, boxes, etc. may result in
(typearea)                many type setting problems.
(typearea)                You should move the command \typearea
(typearea)                outside all groups on input line 21.
```

I am not sure if the `\recalctypearea` is used correctly, but commenting it, definately changes the output. If I comment the `algorithm2e` package, then there is also no warning.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) From the log you showed it looks like you are using `\recalctypearea` inside a group (*e.g.* `{\recalctypearea}`). But the MWE you posted doesn't show that, and it also doesn't produce that warning. Can you please modify the MWE so it shows the warning you mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in older versions of `algorithm2e.sty` that had a stray `{` character.

If you can't update your TeX distribution, copy `algorithm2e.sty` in your working directory and change the line

```
\newboolean{algocf@displaygroupmarkers}{\setboolean{algocf@displaygroupmarkers}{false}
```

into

```
\newboolean{algocf@displaygroupmarkers}\setboolean{algocf@displaygroupmarkers}{false}
```

that is, remove the `{` before `\setboolean`.

You can also load `algorithm2e.sty` after doing `\recalctypearea`, but the issue with the group that doesn't get closed would still be there and may affect big documents.